# OWASP in Classic ASP

Tags: security, asp-classic, owasp

I am trying to use the OWASP with some Classic ASP app, but did not found much information in how to do it, like a step-by-step.

The site seens to be the startup point: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Classic_ASP_Security_Project but someone has a video, or a step-by-step?

Really thankful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no real security in classic ASP.

- There is no authentication model, thus every app has to do their own
  thing
- There is weak session management, with no ability to rotate
  session identifiers or prevent session hijacking. There is no
  anti-CSRF support
- There is no authorization model, thus every app has
  to do their own thing. This means most classic ASP applications have
  access control issues at the presentation, business logic and data
  model layers.
- Input validation is weak as most input validation is
  string replace, which is insufficient.
- There's only
  server.htmlencode() and urlencode for output encoding, but there's no
  other methods for the other 10 or so output contexts, so XSS is
  likely
- There's no method of preventing SQL injection other than using
  stored procedures, but that's fraught with risks if you do it wrong.
- There's no easy method of logging without using an ActiveX server
  object to invoke the Win32 api to use the Windows event logs. This is
  neither easy or simple as these are designed to be used with a
  localized resource and not like syslog.
- Security configuration
  within ASP is minimal reflecting its simple and ancient roots.
  There's very little you can do within code or global.asa to improve
  things.

There was an effort to port ESAPI to classic ASP. I don't think they finished. You might be able to use ESAPI for .NET via COM exports, but I wouldn't necessarily bet on it working.

At this stage, you should be investigating upgrading to ASP.NET 4.0 or later.

thanks

Andrew van der Stock

OWASP Developer Guide 2013 leader

Answer (score 0):

Instead of OWASP, you can use Microsoft AntiXSS which is a .Net library. Only problem is that you can't instanciate it directly from Classic Asp.
You have to create a .net dll (visible from COM) and to wrap functions from AntiXSS in it.

Download : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28589